# Django force query set to return 30 items (even if duplicates are required)

Tags: python, django

I want to use the Django ORM to return 30 items even when less than 30 are in the database for that model. Is there a way to force it to return this many items even if it means returning duplicates?

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(approved=True).order_by('?')[0:30]
```

Is this possible? The above code returns 4 items as that's how many I have in my database.

Would a better approach be to manipulate the projects variable to make it contain 30 items? I would like the projects randomised.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're fine if the result set is 30 or more objects, one way around it is to use `itertools.cycle` for where you don't have enough... (which will start repeating data from the start again)... and limit it using `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
always_30_results = islice(cycle(result_set), 30))
for result in always_30_results:
    print result # or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

nope, you can't. you'll have to concatenate your results till you reach N objects, where N is the number you need.